# What really takes up memory in Python?

Tags: python, memory

Suppose I have 1000 different objects of the same class instantiated, and I assign it to a dictionary whose keys are integers from 1 to 1000, and whose values are those 1000 objects.

Now, I create another dictionary, whose keys are tuples (obj1, 1), (obj2,2), etc. The obj's being those same 1000 objects. And whose values are 1 to 1000.

Does the existence of those 2 dictionaries mean that memory usage will be doubled, because 1000 objects are in each dict's key and values?

They should NOT be, right? Because we are not creating new objects, we are merely assigning references to those same objects. So I can have 1000 similar dictionaries with those objects as either values or as keys (part of a tuple), and have no significant increases in memory usage.

Is that right?

Comment: While you don't need to make copies of the objects themselves, you do need to make pointers to each of them (behind the scenes). If your objects are small, then you will indeed have "significant increases in memory usage".

Comment: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: @aryamccarthy but pointers to those objects are lightweight, so why would I have significant increase?

Comment: @user1008636: Pointers are typically 4-8 bytes. Your objects might not be that much bigger.

Comment: It's about proportions. If your objects are, say, ints, then each one's memory footprint will be close to that of the associated pointer. More pointers—>more memory.

Comment: @user1008636. Define "lightweight". 1000 pointers is 1000 pointers.

Comment: @user2357112 Python objects are actually much bigger, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: That depends on the object. The small ones are only about a factor of two or three times bigger.

Comment: @user2357112. Fair enough. The bare minimum is [`PyObject_HEAD`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject_HEAD), which expands to a size_t and a pointer, with two extra size_t's if `Py_TRACE_REFS` is defined. That and the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are not copied, but referenced.

If your objects are small (e.g. integers), the overhead of a list of tuples or a dict is significant.

If your objects are large (e.g. very long unique strings), the overhead is much less, compared to the size of the objects, so the memory usage will not increase much due to creation of another dict / list of the same objects.